# With DynamoDB.Client.Scan(), how do I retrieve all records where one attribute is not null?

Tags: ruby, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

With DynamoDB.Client.Scan(), how do I retrieve all records where one attribute is not null?

Something like:

```
res = db.scan({
    table_name: "Records", 
    filter_expression: "Fiction != :fiction", 
    expression_attribute_values: { 
        ":fiction" => nil
    }
})
```

Except of course that doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for existing values, you should use the `attribute_exists` keyword, see [the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.ConditionExpressions.html)

`filter_expression: "attribute_exists(Fiction)"`

Also, you are using the wrong comparator. DynamoDB uses `<>` and not `!=` for inequality assertion. [See documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.OperatorsAndFunctions.html)

Comment: Thanks, I found it in a 'useful things' page somewhere but the documentation I was using I was finding utterly impenetrable. I wonder if I was at the wrong one, what's boto3.amazomaws.com?

Comment: Boto3 is the name of the aws sdk for python